# Task: find a 0 point at number line

Tags: geometry

I have a compass and a ruler and I should find a 0 (zero) point at number line.

I have a point A = 1 and B = sqrt(2)

I suppose that I don't know the scale, so I can't just use my ruler to find a 0 (zero) point.

Comment: What does $A=1$ mean?  Do you have a segment of length $1$ in your field?  if so then (by a standard abuse of the method) you can just translate that segment over to your line.  Or do you mean to say that you have a segment of length $\sqrt 2 -1$ and need to construct a segment of length $1$?

Comment: @lulu Yes, I can calculate a segment of length √2−1 and need to construct a segment of length 1. Sorry, don't know much about math terminology in English.

Comment: Oh, no problem.  The phrasing is tricky.  Hint:  let $\alpha = \sqrt 2 -1$.  Remark that $\alpha^2 =3-2\sqrt 2$.  Deduce that $\alpha^2+2\alpha=1$ (check that, I did it mentally).  Now remark that it is easy to construct both $\alpha^2$ and $2\alpha$.

Comment: @lulu Thank you! I've managed to figure this out myself, but I can't understand how can I construct α²?

Comment: Ah, there are general ways to "construct multiplication" (that is, if you have segments of length $a,b$ you can construct one of length $ab$).  For squaring, there are simpler ways to proceed.  See [this](https://www.cs.cas.cz/portal/AlgoMath/Geometry/PlaneGeometry/GeometricConstructions/SquareSquareRootConstruction.htm) for instance.

Comment: @lulu Thanks for the reference! But ain't these methods presume that I should know the length of 1? Which I am trying to find.

Comment: You are absolutely right.  Writing out the way I understand how to construct multiplication, I also assume I have a segment of length $1$ in my field.  Let me think for a bit...

Comment: Ok:   you have a segment of length $\alpha = \sqrt 2 - 1$.  Build the isosceles triangle with legs $\alpha$.  Then the hypotenuse has length $h=\alpha \,\sqrt 2 = 2 - \sqrt 2$.  We then remark that $h+\alpha = 1$

Comment: Note:  it helped me if I thought of it as "given a segment of length $1$, construct a segment of length $\frac 1{\sqrt 2 - 1}=\sqrt 2 +1$".  That is really the same question.

Comment: @lulu Oh my, that wasn't so hard after all =) Thank you so much! It's a pity I was so close and couldn't see it. But next time I definitely will.

Comment: It is an unintuitive problem!  Generally speaking, one always has a segment of length $1$ in the field.  After all, what does length $\alpha$ mean except in reference to a segment of length $1$?  Of course any fixed length works and if you start from a constructible length that you can build all the constructible lengths...but it is a bit hard to think in the different scale.

Comment: Note:  I will post my solution below, so that the question might be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\alpha = \sqrt 2 - 1$.  Thus we are starting with a segment of length $\alpha$ and we wish to construct one of length $1$.

To do it:  first, construct the isosceles right triangle with side lengths $\alpha$.  Then the hypotenuse has length $$h= \sqrt 2 \,\alpha = 2 - \sqrt 2$$

Now just remark that $$1 = h + \alpha$$  and we are done.